# Fix button's position on screen

Tags: android, xml

How do I nail a button down to the screen and fix it there? When you open the keyboard, the button rises above the keyboard, when closed, it goes back down to the screen. I need it to hide under the keyboard, that is, it was constantly on a fixed place.

The code fragment that is responsible for the button:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/confirm_order_layout">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/confirm_order"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@drawable/button_style_green"
            android:text="@string/confirm_order"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please write your question in English, since [Stack Overflow is an English site.](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676)

Comment: check https://ru.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

add below line in activity area of menyfest file.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```